# Error while trying to deploy my code from circleci to firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, circleci

It's the first time Im using CircleCI, so i followed this tutorial [hier](https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploying-an-angular-site-to-firebase-with-circleci-ed881cb6a2fa). I'm using it to build,test and deploy my angular app to firebase.

I tryed looking but couldn't find anything. I tryed changing the node version but it hasn't helped. I also ran the same command for deploying on my machine and there it worked and I look if the dist folders may be empty but it's not.

The deploying part of the circleCI config.yml:

```
deploy:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:chakracore-8.11-browsers-legacy
        working_directory: ~/project
        steps:
            - run:
                name: Show current branch
                command: echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH}
            - restore_cache:
                key: v1-dist-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_BRANCH }}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
            - run:
                name: Install Firebase
                command: npm install --save-dev firebase-tools
            - run:
                name: Deploy Master to Firebase
                command: npm run firebase-deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

The scripts of the package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test-prod":  "ng test --watch=false",
    "firebase-deploy": "firebase deploy",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

The error message when it tries to deploy:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm run firebase-deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN

> first-page@0.0.0 firebase-deploy /home/circleci/project
> firebase deploy

/home/circleci/project/node_modules/open/index.js:29
        ...options
        ^^^^

SyntaxError: Expected identifier, string or number
   at createScript (vm.js:80:3)
   at runInThisContext (vm.js:139:3)
   at Module.prototype._compile (module.js:616:3)
   at Module._extensions[.js] (module.js:663:3)
   at Module.prototype.load (module.js:565:3)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:5)
   at Module._load (module.js:497:3)
   at Module.prototype.require (module.js:596:3)
   at require (internal/module.js:11:7)
   at Anonymous function (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/functions-log.js:12:1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! first-page@0.0.0 firebase-deploy: `firebase deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the first-page@0.0.0 firebase-deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-07-15T16_50_44_850Z-debug.log
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having the same problem.

I set circleci/node:10.16-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` as environment variable. If not please set it. Also you can test it by passing directly into command. like `npm run firebase-deploy --token={your token string}`

Comment: Yeah I did and the token is fine

Comment: you mean by passing token directly, it works fine ?

Comment: Nope, when I pass in the token directly it still doesn't work.